# Install Anaconda and Packages When Building Docker Image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, anaconda

I am looking to install `miniconda` and install `conda` packages when **building** a `docker` image.  I install `miniconda` using the following:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
/bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then I attempt to install conda packages using:

```
RUN conda install numpy
```

I receive the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c conda' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `conda` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

As `stephanmg` suggested, I added `conda` to `PATH` using the following commands and `conda` can now be found.

```
ENV PATH="/opt/conda/bin:${PATH}"
RUN conda
```